# Delphi Как cохранить контекст или стек вызовов в какую то структуру

Tags: delphi, стек, context

Как cохранить контекст или стек вызовов в какую то структуру
потом заменить стек его на другую структуру и продолжить выполнение программы.
Появилась такая задача от того что не получается создать бесконечное кол-во потоков
для каждого клиента.

Есть 1 поток в котором много клиентов нужно пока выполняется sleep для одного клиета проверить запустить и выполнить другие клиенты ( до 1-го sleep )

Казалось бы можно просто в цикле пройтись и по очереди их выполнить, но вот
цикл одного клиента оч долгий и еще со Sleep

Хотелось бы в середине (на рисунке красным) во время sleep
проверить может нужно запустить другой контекст.
Пока условный sleep в CLient1 идет запустится Client2 и поток не будет простаивать.
A потом вернутся на тоже место когда sleep начался
и продолжить выполнение проги

Если стек не трогать то он переполнится(войдет в рекурсию). Подскажите какие алгоритмы есть на подобные случаи.

Про отдельный поток для каждого клиента я конечно знаю от этого способа к этому  и пришел что не получатся создать очень много потоков на машине из за размера стека под каждый поток.

[image: Схема]

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит пересмотреть архитектуру в сторону выделения независимых "порций работы со всеми нужными им *контекстами*", которые бы вы выдавали рабочим потокам.

Comment: https://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/06/omnithreadlibrary-20-sneak-preview-1.html ? Хотя здесь наверное лучше даже https://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/11/multistage-processes-with.html